# need to total number of rows in two csv files and add them together in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, count, sum

In pandas with python I need to total the number of rows in each csv file then add them together under the variable total_months but I keep getting an error and I have no idea what I am doing incorrectly not sure what attributes i should use to get this working. what i want to do is count up the total number of rows in each file and then add them together

```
# Modules
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

# Read my budget data into pandas
df1 = pd.read_csv(budget_1_csv)
df2 = pd.read_csv(budget_2_csv)


budget_one_months = df1["Date"].value_counts
budget_two_months = df2["Date"].value_counts
```

I try this

```
total_months = [budget_one_months].value_counts() + ["budget_two_months"].value_counts()
```

And get this error message

```
    #  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-2cd6e6e55bc7> in <module>()

----> 1 total_months = [budget_one_months].value_counts() + ["budget_two_months"].value_counts()
      2 total_months

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value_counts'




    total_months = [budget_one_months].value_counts() + ["budget_two_months"].value_counts()
    total_months
```

Answer (score 0):

- You have a typo `[budget_one_months].value_counts() + ["budget_two_months"].value_counts()` because you want to call the variable `budget_two_months` and not the string `"budget_two_months"`
- You forgot the parenthesis when defining `budget_one_months` and `budget_two_months`. It should be `budget_one_months = df1["Date"].value_counts()` and same for `budget_two_months`
- You should not call `value_counts()` again. You're calling these methods on lists while they are `pd.DataFrame()` methods. And you already have these counts computed because you created variables `budget_one_months` and  `budget_two_months` just above.

I think you just want to use this :

```
total_months = budget_one_months + budget_two_months
```

Comment: yea sorry that was definitely a typo. your solution is the first method i tried but this is the result when i run it:

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-6fe563f3b163> in <module>()
----> 1 total_months = budget_one_months + budget_two_months

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'method'

Comment: Ok perfect. You can accept the answer then. Good evening, careful with typos !

Comment: Im sorry i did have a typo but im still getting an error when I try your method of just adding the variable ive already created. do you see the comment above? the error is as follows ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-6fe563f3b163> in <module>()
----> 1 total_months = budget_one_months + budget_two_months

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'method'

Comment: You must add parenthesis when you define `budget_one_months` and `budget_two_months`.
`budget_one_months = df1["Date"].value_counts()` and `budget_two_months = df2["Date"].value_counts()`

Answer (score 0):

```
total_months = budget_one_months + budget_two_months
```

You must add parenthesis when you `define budget_one_months` and `budget_two_months`.

```
budget_one_months = df1["Date"].value_counts()
```

and

```
budget_two_months = df2["Date"].value_counts()
```